# Requests + s3 painfully slow

Tags: python, multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, python-requests

I'm using Python's `requests` with `smart_open` to download a file (a `.tif` file, in case that helps), and upload it to an S3 bucket without saving any temporary file. I'm looping through a few thousands of URLs per request. This is the function I wrote:

```py
def stream_download_s3(url,
                       aws_key,
                       aws_secret,
                       aws_bucket_name,
                       path,
                       auth):
    """
    Stream files from request to S3
    """

    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth}',
               'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15'}
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=aws_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret
    )

    bucket_path_strip = path[5:]
    bucket_name_strip = aws_bucket_name[5:]

    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)
        try:
            with s.get(url) as r:
                if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
                    download_files = [link.contents[0] for link in
                                      soup.find_all('a') if '.tif' in
                                     link.contents[0]]

                    for file_name in download_files:
                        save_file = os.path.join(path,
                                                 file_name)

                        if check_s3_exists(session, 
                                           bucket_name_strip,
                                           os.path.join(bucket_path_strip, file_name)):
                            print(f'S3: {os.path.join(path, file_name)} already exists. Skipping download')
                        else:
                            with s.get(url + file_name) as file_request:
                                if file_request.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                                    with smart_open.open(save_file, 'wb', transport_params=dict(session=session)) as so:
                                        so.write(file_request.content)

                else:
                    print(f'Request GET failed with {r.content} [{r.url}]')

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as err:
            print(f'{err}')
```

This function is making a first request to scrape all the available images URLs (that's the `bs4` part), and then looping through all the retrieved URLs and download their content. The returned request content it's a binary  that I send to the `smart_open`'s `open` function to upload to S3.

The whole process is taking ~150 minutes for 510 images (less than 2 Gb), whereas  a combination of `wget` and `aws s3 ls` does the same in ~86 mins (`wget` took `1h 26m 46s`, and `s3 cp` took seconds).

#### Some options in consideration:

- I'm working in an AWS machine, although some APIs would ban AWS-like IPs, this seems not to be the case. If it is making the download slower, I don't know. Also, S3 and EC2 are in the same region.
- I know that `stream=True` in the `requests.get()` is an alternative, but as far as I know, that is mainly useful for streaming big files without filling up the memory. Does that might change anything?
- A similar implementation with `io.BytesIO` give similar results. Am I doing something wrong there?
- I use `requests` because I like the API (*a lot*!), but if there's any other alternative, I am open to try :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way!

I realize that the problem wasn't the uploading process. Rather, since the requested server was slowing down my requests, using multiprocess made more sense. I didn't use `multiprocess` right away; this function is a moving piece in a [Luigi](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) pipeline, so I wasn't sure how can I use multiprocess in a code that is already spawning multiple treats per Task.

I give it a try and used `concurrent.futures` (I think only for > 3.6), and the results were more than satisfactory. This is the same function above, but with parallelization:

```py
def stream_download_s3_parallel(url,
                                aws_key,
                                aws_secret,
                                aws_bucket_name,
                                path,
                                auth,
                                max_workers=10):
    """
    Stream files from request to S3
    """

    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {auth}',
               'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.1 Safari/605.1.15'}
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=aws_key,
        aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret
    )

    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.headers.update(headers)
        try:
            with s.get(url) as r:
                if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
                    download_files = [link.contents[0] for link in
                                      soup.find_all('a') if '.tif' in
                                     link.contents[0]]

                    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
                        future_to_url = {executor.submit(requests_to_s3, 
                                                         url,
                                                         file_name,
                                                         aws_bucket_name,
                                                         path,
                                                         auth,
                                                         session): file_name for file_name in download_files}
                        return future_to_url
```

Here `requests_to_s3` is a simple function that takes several parameters needed for submit the request and to upload to S3 using `smart_open`, basically the same code in the question. The `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` return a generator of all the processes ran in the pool. Since I'm saving this to S3 directly, it doesn't make sense to play with this, but if it is your case, you can do something like:

```
results_process = []
for treat_proc in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
    results_process.append(threat_proc.result())
```

This will add whatever your function is returning a putting it in the `results_process` list.

I'm still not sure if I prefer this way to multiprocess, rather than the old `multiprocessing` library, it seems [cleaner](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/concurrent.futures.html).